# setting variables in a for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this code

```
for i in range(10):
    variablename = "file" + str(i)
```

and I want to be able to go generate variables depending on the `i` variable
like if range was to 10 would have variables like this

- file1
- file2
- file3
- file4
- file5
- file6
- file7
- file8
- file9
- file10

How would I do this?

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: why don't you use a list with all filenames?

Comment: why not use a dictionary for this??

Comment: just use a `list` and `append`, [look here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: okay so I don't know how to use a dictionary and Ruben bermudez I want it to work wnatever the range is so if its 10 then it does ten variables but if its 20 it does 20 a so on so fourth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary

```
dict = {}
for i in range(10):
    dict["file" + str(i)] = "value for this var"
```

then you can obtain a value using the variable name

```
f1 = dict["file1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `globals()` function which contains a dictionary of all the global variables. To which I recommend reading these two pages if you are unfamiliar with scope, or dictionaries

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

[Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

```
for i in range(10):
    globals()["file" + str(i)] = "newvarvalue!" + str(i)
print file0
print file1
print file2
print file3
print file4
print file5
print file6
print file7
print file8
print file9
```

**EDIT** removed locals() from solution

Comment: generally speaking this is a bad idea ... I think

Comment: @Joran Beasley much agreed.

Comment: @Joran Beasley however, it does directly answers op's question

Answer (score 0):

list comprehensions

```
filenames = ["file%d.txt"%i for i in range(1,11)]
```

or if you want them as variable names store them in a dictionary as suggested in [P0lyb1us's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670457/541038)

Answer (score -4):

You you need to give `range()` two arguments for it to work so you should change your code to:

```
for i in range(1,11):
     variablename = "file" + str(i)
```

Comment: No. He merely needs to change `range(10)` into something like `range(1,11)` instead.

Comment: I don't think the question is "why am I getting file0 instead of file1 as my first element?" but rather, "how do I take this string, and make it be the name of a variable?"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).